# CLI app test fails if `cargo build` is not run first

Tags: unit-testing, rust, command-line-interface

I have a pure Rust CLI app that I'm unit testing, and if I run

```
cargo clean
cargo test --release
```

it fails to find the binary, but if I run

```
cargo clean
cargo build --release
cargo test --release
```

it works.  Is there a way to tell cargo not to run the test until the binary app has been built?

Here's my test harness:

```
#[cfg(test)]
pub mod tests {
    use std::process::Command;

    use assert_cmd::prelude::{CommandCargoExt, OutputAssertExt};
    use predicates::prelude::predicate;

    #[test]
    fn test_that_cli_app_produces_result() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
        let mut cmd = Command::cargo_bin("fastsim-cli")?;
        let mut cyc_file = project_root::get_project_root().unwrap();
        cyc_file.push("../fastsim/resources/cycles/udds.csv");
        assert!(cyc_file.exists());
        let mut veh_file = project_root::get_project_root().unwrap();
        veh_file.push("../fastsim/resources/vehdb/2012_Ford_Fusion.yaml");
        assert!(veh_file.exists());

        cmd.args([
            "--cyc-file",
            cyc_file.to_str().unwrap(),
            "--veh-file",
            veh_file.to_str().unwrap(),
        ]);
        cmd.assert()
            .success()
            .stdout(predicate::str::contains("32.4"));

        Ok(())
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you may be able to hack it by adding the crate as a `[dev-dependencies]` to itself. But generally, I would not write tests this way. This is not the intended way to do integration tests and if you only run tests on the compiled binary you will not be able to generate code coverage or ensure it is working in the way you are intending. I would recommend going with Kevin's answer instead or changing this test to directly test the functions which perform the operation you are testing.

Answer (score 4):

From the `#[cfg(test)] mod tests {` I am guessing that this is code that exists inside of your library or binary source files. That is not the correct location for a test which needs to run a built binary. Instead, you should write [a so-called “integration test”](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/cargo-targets.html#integration-tests) which are located in the `tests/` directory next to `src/`, and are separate compilation targets (so that they can be built after everything else). Cargo specifically provides for testing binaries via integration tests:

> Binary targets are automatically built if there is an integration test. This allows an integration test to execute the binary to exercise and test its behavior. The `CARGO_BIN_EXE_<name>` environment variable is set when the integration test is built so that it can use the `env` macro to locate the executable.

If you're already using an integration test, then something else has gone wrong that isn't obvious from your description, because Cargo *should* be building the binary, as per the documentation.

Comment: Integration tests don't need `#[cfg(test)]` since they are separate from the project so it seems highly likely that the test shown above is part of the project structure.

Comment: @Kevin Reid, would this behave any differently if the CLI app crate I'm testing belongs to a `[workspace]`?  Can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: @Chad It should work, as long as the test is in the same **package** (workspace member) as the binary. If it still doesn't work, something elsewhere may be wrong (that I haven't thought of), or maybe you've found some kind of Cargo bug.

Comment: I've tried creating a separate crate, which fails because there's no way to have a binary crate as a dependency, and also making a tests folder in parrallel with `src/` of the CLI app crate, and the latter just does not run the test.

Comment: @Chad A `tests/my_test.rs` file (positioned according to the [standard project layout](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/guide/project-layout.html) _should_ be run automatically. If it's not, then something else is wrong.